# Dell Latitude 5400 64GB RAM ? (2x32GB)

Tags: memory

can Dell Latitude 5400 run with 64GB RAM ?

It has intel-core-i58365u,
which according to [ark.intel.com](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/193555/intel-core-i58365u-processor-6m-cache-up-to-4-10-ghz.html) can hold up to 64GB unbuffered RAM.
But just don't know to check if the motherboard/bios RAM slot can have 2x32GB

According to https://www.compuram.biz/memory/dell/notebook/latitude/5000-series/5400/ it can have 64GB

Answer (score 1):

If both Dell and Intel tell you you can run 64 GB of ram in that laptop, go for it. But according to Dell and Crucial, you can only get 16GB in one slot, so you can go the risky side and get 64GB, or go the no risk way and get 32GB (which is enough for +- all use cases)

Comment: thanks, yeah i have to find out if one slot can support 32gb or not. will ask computer stores around me if they have old 32gb ram to test on 1 slot.